# SetWrappedData for DataModel isn't working properly

Tags: java, jsf, nullpointerexception

I have a form with a panelGrid, where the user puts in some data:

```
<h:form>
    <p:panelGrid var="workOrder" value="#{WorkOrder}" columns="2"
        headerClass="header" footerClass="footer">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{msg.project_number}: " for="projectNr" />
        <p:column>
            <p:inputText id="projectNr"
                value="#{mbWorkOrderController.workOrderCurrent.projectNr}"
                required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.input_missing}"
                maxlength="6" />
        </p:column>
        <p:outputLabel value="#{msg.date}: " for="date" />
        <p:column>
            <p:calendar id="date"
                value="#{mbWorkOrderController.workOrderCurrent.date}"
                mode="popup" navigator="true" showOn="button"
                pattern="dd.MM.yyy" />
        </p:column>
    </p:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton action="#{mbWorkOrderController.saveWorkOrder()}"
        value="#{msg.save}" style="margin-top: 10px" />
    <p:commandButton
        action="#{mbWorkOrderController.cancelWorkOrder()}"
        value="#{msg.cancel}" immediate="true" style="margin-top: 10px" />
</h:form>
```

When the user clicks "save", the method `saveWorkOrder()` is called. Inside, I am trying to use the method `setWrappedData()` on a `DataModel` variable, after I create the result using the `EntityManagers`s `createNamedQuery()`:

```
public String saveWorkOrder() {
    try {
        utx.begin();
        workOrderCurrent = em.merge(workOrderCurrent);
        em.persist(workOrderCurrent);
        List<WorkOrder> resultList = em.createNamedQuery("SelectWorkOrders").getResultList();
        workOrdersList.setWrappedData(resultList);
        utx.commit();
    } catch (NotSupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RollbackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HeuristicMixedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HeuristicRollbackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "rainErosion";
}
```

Unfortunately I am getting a `NullPointerException` in `setWrappedData(resultList)` although `resultList` contains one element (with the actual user input) and is not pointing to `Null`, so normaly this shouldn't happen.

Does anyone know, why this happens?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Are you capable of reading stack traces and debugging variables? Have you already excluded `workOrdersList` itself from being `null`? If not, then I agree Jens' closure.

Comment: True, I added a `@PostConstruct` method where I create a new `workOrdersList` object. It works now. Sorry.